"DllNotFoundException: nanosockets" and "EntryPointNotFoundException: nanosockets_address_set_ip", only on MacOS
I'm trying to make a Unity multiplayer game using Photon Fusion. The multiplayer matchmaking and lobby system I created works fine on Windows, but when I try to create or join a match on Mac, it says that there was a libnanosocket error.
When I open the libnanosocket asset in the Unity inspector, it says it is for Intel CPUs, even though my Mac is M2. When I try to change it, and I click apply, it just reverts back to Intel. No matter what I do it doesn't change from Intel, could someone please help me find a solution?
Here was the specific error I got when I tried to create a match on Mac:
DllNotFoundException: nanosockets assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
Fusion.Sockets.NetAddress.CreateFromIpPort (System.String ip, System.UInt16 port) (at Fusion/Fusion.Sockets/NetAddress.cs:145)
Fusion.Sockets.NetAddress.Any (System.UInt16 port) (at Fusion/Fusion.Sockets/NetAddress.cs:116)
NetworkRunnerHandler.CreateGame (System.String sessionName, System.String sceneName) (at Assets/_Scripts/Network/NetworkRunnerHandler.cs:176)
MainMenuUIHandler.OnStartNewSessionClicked () (at Assets/_Scripts/UI/MainMenuUIHandler.cs:64)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent/UnityEvent.cs:178)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/artifacts/generated/UnityEvent/UnityEvent_0.cs:57)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:70)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:114)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler,
UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem ExecuteEvents.cs:57)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:272)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:530)

I've tried to change it in the file itself, but it's a binary file and I don't know how to edit/change it. I'm also worried that even if I can change the file itself, it will revert back once I try to join/create a match on Mac (same as what happened when I changed the setting in unity).
I reset the DLL and it seemed to work, but now I get a new error message:
EntryPointNotFoundException: nanosockets_address_set_ip assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
Fusion.Sockets.NetAddress.CreateFromIpPort (System.String ip, System.UInt16 port) (at Fusion/Fusion.Sockets/NetAddress.cs:145)
Fusion.Sockets.NetAddress.Any (System.UInt16 port) (at Fusion/Fusion.Sockets/NetAddress.cs:116)
NetworkRunnerHandler.CreateGame (System.String sessionName, System.String sceneName) (at Assets/_Scripts/Network/NetworkRunnerHandler.cs:176)
MainMenuUIHandler.OnStartNewSessionClicked () (at Assets/_Scripts/UI/MainMenuUIHandler.cs:64)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent/UnityEvent.cs:178)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/artifacts/generated/UnityEvent/UnityEvent_0.cs:57)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:70)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:114)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:57)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:272)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:530)


That's my bad, I accidentally posted the wrong message. I just fixed it to show what should be the proper one. The error is the DllNotFoundException.

This post has some solutions that may work.  Sounds like there are 2 versions of the dll, one specifically for intel (which may be what is currently configured for you).  If one of those solutions works for you, please add the detailed solution as an answer.

I think I fixed the Libnanosockets error, but now I get a new error message.

CreateFromIpPort (System.String ip, System.UInt16 port)  looks like the ip is null.  Might be configuration issue.

Does it tell me where to find the configuration?
